How to Set Up and Evaluate a go-cel Expression with Protocol Buffers in Go
I am trying to set up a go-cel environment and evaluate an expression using Protocol Buffers in Go. I have the following code. However, I am encountering issues with setting up the environment and evaluating the expression. Specifically, I am getting errors during the environment creation, compilation, or evaluation steps.
Can someone help me understand what I might be doing wrong and how to correctly set up and evaluate a go-cel expression with Protocol Buffers in Go?
import gatewaypb "gogoproto/xxxxx"

req := gatewaypb.NoteRequest{
        Note: &gatewaypb.Note{
            Note: &google_protobuf2.StringValue{Value: "noteval"},
        },
    }

    // Step 2: Set up the go-cel environment
    env, err := cel.NewEnv(
        cel.Types(&gatewaypb.NoteRequest{}, &gatewaypb.Note{}),
        cel.Declarations(
            decls.NewVar("req", decls.NewObjectType("gatewaypb.NoteRequest")),
        ),
    )
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("env creation error:", err)
        return
    }

    // Step 3: Create and evaluate a go-cel expression
    ast, iss := env.Compile(`req.Note.Note.Value == "noteval"`)
    if iss.Err() != nil {
        fmt.Println("compile error:", iss.Err())
        return
    }

    prg, err := env.Program(ast)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("program creation error:", err)
        return
    }

    // Evaluate the expression
    out, _, err := prg.Eval(map[string]interface{}{
        "req": req,
    })
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("evaluation error:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Evaluation result:", out)

Error is :
env creation error:gatewaypb.NoteRequest is not recognized type.

You dont post any error

updated with error details.
